# VS 2015 memory leak on startup?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I start VS 2015, it become unresponsive as soon as it opens and use more and more memory until it crashes. Any clue on this will be very appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution on : http://mikeperetz.blogspot.ca/2014/04/visual-studio-2012-stop-responding-on.html

Run this command : "devenv /ResetSettings" in cmd.exe